# How to access information in PHP object

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I've tried a number of things but I'm not used to dealing with objects this complex. How do I access the "Case Disposition" so I can save it to a variable? The below is part of the var_dump of the object (it's very long).

I've tried converting it to an array and doing something like below but that just returns empty.

```
$myarray['CaseData']['Case Information']['Case Disposition'];
```

Here's part of the var_dump of the object I'm sent.

```
`object(CaseData)#1 (1) {
  ["caseData":"CaseData":private]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Case Information"]=>
    array(10) {
      ["Case Disposition"]=>
      string(5) "TRIAL"
      ["Case Number"]=>
      string(10) "1D00297207"
      ["Case Status"]=>
      string(6) "CLOSED"
      ["Case Type"]=>
      string(8) "CRIMINAL"
      ["Court System"]=>
      string(54) "DISTRICT COURT FOR MONTGOMERY COUNTY - CRIMINAL SYSTEM"
      ["District Code"]=>
      string(2) "06"
      ["Document Type"]=>
      string(7) "SUMMONS"
      ["Issued Date"]=>
      string(10) "11/09/2013"
      ["Location Code"]=>
      string(2) "02"
      ["Tracking No"]=>
      string(12) "131001793941"
    }
    ["Charge and Disposition Information"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(17) {
        ["Amended Date"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["Amt Suspended"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["CICF"]=>
          string(5) "$0.00"
           ["Court Costs"]=>
          string(5) "$0.00"
          ["Fine"]=>
          string(5) "$0.00"
        }
        ["CJIS Code"]=>
        string(6) "2 2411"`
```

Comment: Humble question: what is this `["caseData":"CaseData":private]`?

Comment: try $myarray->CaseData['Case Information']['Case Disposition']

Comment: PHP has some great [documentation on objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php). Have you had a look at it?

Comment: one question,what isn't it all an object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think:

```
$CaseData->caseData['Case Information']['Case Disposition'];
```

`$CaseData` is an object, not an array, and you access class properties by using `->` instead of `[]`. Unfortunately, `$caseData` (**not** `$CaseData`) is a private property of the `$CaseData` object, so you will only be able to access it from inside the class.

Can you make the `$caseData` property public, or add a `getCaseData()` method the `$CaseData` class? Something like

```
class CaseData
{
    // ... existing code ...

    public function getCaseData()
    {
        return $this->caseData;
    }
}
```

Then you can get to the 'Case Disposition' by doing:

```
$CaseData->getCaseData()['Case Information']['Case Disposition'];
```

Even better, add a `getCaseDisposition()` method to the `CaseData` class, so you can just do:

```
$CaseData->getCaseDisposition();
```

Comment: Thanks didn't understand the private limitations of private. I'll get the OP to add a class to return right information so I can use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `$myarray` variable consists of a `CaseData` instance. Instance properties must be accessed with `->`, and array properties with square brackets.

So the value you're looking for must be accessed this way:

```
$myarray->caseData['Case Information']['Case Disposition'];
```

Edit: I have been warned that `$caseData` is a private property so you can't access it directly. The instance probably has an accessor method so you can access the instance's  properties using it. Something like:

```
$data = $myarray->getCaseData();
$data['Case Information']['Case Disposition']; // the info you need
```

Or, in a more concise way (depends on your PHP version):

```
$myarray->getCaseData()['Case Information']['Case Disposition']; // the info you need
```

You can list the instance's available public methods with:

```
print_r(get_class_methods($myarray));
```

Comment: Probably the instance has an accessor method, like `getCaseData()` or something. The OP must see the public methods with `var_dump(get_class_methods($myarray));`

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want:

```
$foo = $myarray['caseData']['Case Information']['Case Disposition'];
```

It may also help to have the original array posted.

Comment: It looks like `caseData` is an object, not an array - and it is also private.